# Combo Box list can't display data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am developing a combo box whenever i select something in the contractor column( as per attach in the link) , the vehicle combo box will retrieve the info from database based on the contractor selection.

Problems faced:
Vehicle combo box can't display the data based on the contractor selection.

Illustration about the interface design:

[image: illustration about the interface design]

---

I've attached in the first part of the code which is my HTML table code.

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name='opt_contractor[]' id='opt_contractor' onChange="getState(this.value);" <?php if ($view==1) {?> disabled <?php }?> >
    <option>-- Select One --</option>
    <?php 
    foreach ($get_contractor as $contractor ){
    ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $contractor->ref_id;?>'<?php if($contractor->ref_id == $reqtype){echo ' selected';}?>><?php echo $contractor->ref_desc;?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="opt_vehicle[]" id="opt_vehicle" >
    <option value="">-- Select Vehicle --</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

---

Script

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}


function getState(countryId)
{
   var strURL="refresh.php?country="+countryId;
   var req = getXMLHTTP();
   if (req)
   {
      req.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if (req.readyState == 4)
        {
        // only if "OK"
        if (req.status == 200)
        {
          document.getElementById('opt_vehicle').innerHTML=req.responseText;
        } else {
          alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
        }
      }
      req.open("GET", strURL, true);
      req.send(null);
   }
}
```

---

PHP CODE

```
$query ="SELECT ref_id, ref_desc FROM ref_mst WHERE ref_val5 = '" . $country . "'";
$result = $db->query($query);

?>
<select name="opt_vehicle" >
<option>Select State</option>
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['ref_id'] ?> ><?php echo $row['ref_desc'] ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

For this part( refer php code), i've made several attempt to fix the problem occur, i've attached the problem in below as well.

```
1. <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
2. <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
3. <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
```

Illustration about the error:
[image]

Comment: Is there any error in your console ?

Comment: yes, there is, steve just edited my question, can you please check. i am still new to this.

Comment: Your query failing due to some reason .may be database not connected well .

Comment: My other columns are getting the correct info from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem, instead of using

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
```

---

I used this method

```
$results = $db->get_results($query);
<?php
foreach($results as $vhc) {
 ?>
<option value='<?php echo $vhc->ref_id;?>'><?php echo $vhc->ref_desc; ?> </option>
```

---

I've attached in the modification of the codes i've made to resolved my issue.

```
if(!empty($contract)) {
$query = "SELECT ref_id, ref_desc FROM ref_mst WHERE ref_val5 = '" .$contract. "'";
$results = $db->get_results($query);
?>
<select name="opt_vehicle" >
<option value="">Select Vehicle ....</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $vhc) {
 ?>
<option value='<?php echo $vhc->ref_id;?>'><?php echo $vhc->ref_desc; ?> </option>
<?php
} ?>
<select>
<?php }
```

Thank you once again to Ajmal Praveen for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Viewed your PHP Code**

I think there is a Issue in your PHP Code Kindly Replace it with my code below

```
    <?php
//re updated the query code instead , now used the AND and markers
    $query ="SELECT `ref_id` AND `ref_desc` FROM `ref_mst` WHERE `ref_val5` = '.$country.'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    ?>
    <select name="opt_vehicle" >
    <option>Select State</option>
    <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
            echo $tableRow[$key];
        }
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tableRow['ref_id']; ?>"><?php echo $tableRow['ref_desc']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

To Debug your Self
i was Echo'ed there

```
echo $value;
```

There is Issues with the Quotation i Think.. So give a try and Update me.. Thank you..

and Kindly Try to use PDO Prepared Statements or Mysqli Prepared statements, in Your Normal Code Your are using Direct Queries to DB.

Comment: I still facing the problem as shown in "llustration about the error: "

Comment: Hello, Nian I was Re updated that code as you said

"I still facing the problem as shown in "llustration about the error: ""

Now array values are Looped.

Comment: yeah, just tried your code, but i still can't figure out why the error("illustration about the error") still showing in my compiler. I think it's related to this line of code <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> .

Comment: Kindly provide screen shots of the error and html output Source too.
are you trying this code in a Live server?

Comment: i am doing this using wamp server. i might need some time to upload on live server( maybe a free server ).  May i know what are the preferable methods for you to help me?

Comment: Whenever i was free i can help you, Try to check with a live server and I can help you there i got login info before that u need contact through PM<, Stackoverflow doesnt support messaging right?
and
Need to debug each lines,
When you execute the code are you getting the array value? or Only error?

Comment: Nian, re updated the Code query instead of using , i have added AND and markers. I have checked query with my different DB in my phpmyadmin it was working fine. So you need Confirm your DB structure has all the fields and data etc...

Comment: Thank you Ajmal, will try this out and will feedback to you, currently i am rushing for other projects. Thank you so much man for the help,appreciate your help man

Comment: I've resolved my problem. It's just the method of getting and outputting the variables.

Comment: Thank you. Got it dude..  